# Can't get simple Coinbase button in Node to work

Tags: button, bitcoin

I created an account on Coinbase.com, edited the Merchant profile and generated simple button code so that it should display a window and they'd manage the Bitcoin payment session.

I'm trying to add this to a Jade-rendered page.

Page:

```
//- Incoming params: title, user, message
extends layout
block content
  section.css-table
    section.one-column
      section.cell
        a(class="coinbase-button", data-code="SANDBOXDATACODE", data-button-style="custom_large", data-custom="Order Sat 03 21 2015 - Sample UserName", href="https://sandbox.coinbase.com/checkouts/SANDBOXDATACODE") Pay With Bitcoin
        block javascript
          script("src"="https://www.coinbase.com/assets/button.js")
```

Note that I'm attempting to connect to the sandbox rather than the live (www) server.  Using www still doesn't work.  The code is almost identical to the code they generated for me--I did have to change the JavaScript reference so that it would work correctly in Jade.

The button renders correctly after a two-second delay.  Pressing the button darkens the window content in preparation to then (hopefully) displaying the popup window content with their form.  It just never diplays.

Nothing from the button.js script prints anything to the console.log, btw.  I've tried this from two different networks.  I don't think my Windows firewall is blocking the outbound https attempt since it's pulling the JavaScript.  Note also that I'm testing this locally:  http://127.0.0.1:8080.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth I ended up using the following approach instead.

```
//- Incoming params: title, user, message, ordernum, isProduction
extends layout
block content
  section.css-table
    section.one-column
      section.cell
        if (isProduction)
          iframe(id='coinbase_inline_iframe_PRODUCTIONDATACODE'
            src='https://www.coinbase.com/checkouts/PRODUCTIONDATACODE/inline?c=#{ordernum}'
            style='width: 460px; height: 380px; border: none; box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);'
            allowtransparency='true'
            frameborder='0'
            align='center'
            )
        else
          iframe(id='coinbase_inline_iframe_SANDBOXDATACODE'
            src='https://sandbox.coinbase.com/checkouts/SANDBOXDATACODE/inline?c=#{ordernum}'
            style='width: 460px; height: 380px; border: none; box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);'
            allowtransparency='true'
            frameborder='0'
            align='center'
            )
```